# im on linux and this script wont wort for me but it works for my friends on windows 7

Tags: python, pygame, sys

me and my friends have bean working on a game we only just started today and so far the script runs fine on my friends computers who have windows 7, but on my computer which runs linux mint 14 when i run the script it just gives me the sam error, my friends used to have this error but then they fixed it but it still wont work on my computer.

this is the script so far:

```
#Imports Modules Related to the Operating System and Pygame
import pygame, random, os, sys, time, math
from pygame.locals import*
pygame.init()


#Appends all our folders to the System Path
sys.path.append('/Scripts')
sys.path.append('/Images/Advertising+Cinematics')
sys.path.append('/Images/Alien_Races')
sys.path.append('/Images/Charecter')
sys.path.append('/Images/Items')
sys.path.append('/Images/Misc')
sys.path.append('/Images/Npc')
sys.path.append('/Images/Terrain_Indoor')
sys.path.append('/Images/Terrain_Outdoor')
sys.path.append('/Images/weapons')

#Imports User Created Scripts for Game
import weapons, misc_functions,terrain_generation,items,initiation

#Defines Neccisary Values

FPS=pygame.time.Clock().get_fps()
FPS_CAP=pygame.time.Clock().tick(60)

#Creates Infinte Game Loop
while 1:


    #Creates Event Loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        pass
        #Checks For User Generated Actions
```

and this is the error it gives me when i run the script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/claude/Dropbox/Bowtie/Prisim/Prisim.py", line 20, in <module>
    import weapons, misc_functions,terrain_generation,items,initiation
ImportError: No module named weapons
```

there are probably other ptoplems with this script so far but we waont to work out them on our own, i just want to know why this script works for my friends but not me?

thank you

Comment: He has modules that you don't.  Ask him to provide those modules.

Answer (score 0):

Check the spelling of `weapons` vs `Weapons` in the `sys.path.append()` line. Maybe you need a capital `W`? This would not matter on Windows but could cause what you suggest on Linux (since on Linux, file names are case sensitive).

Comment: So, do you have a directory called `/Images` in your root directory? Using absolute paths is going to be awkward because you will all have to make sure you've got the same files in the same root directories. I would suggest using relative paths instead.

Comment: we all share a dropbox account so everything is in the same directory

Comment: Well, that's not what is reflected in your `sys.path.append(...)` lines. You are using absolute paths there, which on Windows will try to find them at the root of the current drive letter, and on Linux will try to find them at the root directory `/`. This is likely the source of your problem.

Comment: yeah, its very akward, all my friends have just relised the problem, any ideas on how we can all work on this online?

Comment: Instead of using paths like `/Images/...`, just use `Images/...` without the leading slash. That will cause Python to look in the `Images` subdirectory of the current directory, instead of looking in the root directory.

Comment: so i did that, and i think it help but i still get the same error no module named weapone

Comment: Well, that means Python can't find your module. Since you (or a colleague) wrote that module, you're going to have to locate it on your system and make sure that you tell Python exactly where it is. There's not much more we can do from here.